# Httprequest error. Help to make the correct request

Tags: salesforce, httprequest, box-api

I have example request:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F parent_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID
```

My request returns an error missing_parameter","name":"parent","message":"'parent' is required".

This is my request:

```
    String boundary = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime());
    String body = '------------' + boundary + '\r\n';
    body +='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileName"; FileName="' + fileBody +'"\r\n';
    body+='Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n';
    if ((contentType == null) || (contentType == '')){contentType = 'application/octet-stream';}
    body+='Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n';
    body+=EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBody);
    body +='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Parent"; \r\n';
    body+='Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n';
    if ((contentType == null) || (contentType == '')){contentType = 'application/octet-stream';}
    body+='Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n';
    body+=0;

    body+='\r\n------------' + boundary + '--'; 

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------' + boundary);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));

    req.setBody(body);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken.token__c);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content');

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for the ID of the folder you want to upload to.

try changing this line:

```
body +='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Parent"; \r\n';
```

to:

```
body +='Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_id"; \r\n';
```

EDIT: though I have to ask, why are you sending the whole file body as the file name?